# Difference between parallel and standard form pid controller in simulink?

Tags: control, matlab, simulink, equation, block-diagram

What is the difference between parallel and standard form of pid controller that is provided by pidtool in Matlab  simulink? In terms of block diagram?

Comment: please read the documentation that comes with it.

Answer (score 2):

The equations are slightly different and its a difference between time constants and gains.

[image]

Source: https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/proportional-integral-derivative-pid-controllers.html

Comment: How will be both these different in terms of block diagram?

Comment: @Man Ah ha, you see, that's the fun part of engineering. The block diagram is how _**you**_ define to be as long as you're being consistent with your specifications.

Comment: They are equivalent, only the constants change.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel form means controller will be connected  parallel to plant and standard form means controller will be connected in series .

Comment: Please edit your question and add enough information so we can understand what you are asking. Is a plant something that grows in the ground, a manufacturing facility, etc?